# Showing: TypeError: moment is not a function when we use daterangpicker in Vue JS component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, momentjs

Here is my component code.

```
<template>
  <input type="text" class="form-control custom-daterangepicker">
</template>

<script setup>
import moment from "moment/moment";
import {onMounted} from "vue";
import "daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css";
import "daterangepicker/daterangepicker";
onMounted(() => {
  $('.custom-daterangepicker').daterangepicker();
})
</script>
```

Following error is showing.

[image]

Comment: Have you solved it yet?

Comment: I have the same issue. But not find out a way